# How to get data correctly into dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've read a csv file into a pandas data frame, df, of 84 rows. There are n (6 in this example) values in a column that I want to use as keys in a dictionary, data, to convert to a data frame df_data. Column names in df_data come from the columns in df.

I can do most of this successfully, but I'm not getting the actual data into the dataframe. I suspect the problem is in my loop creating the dictionary, but can't figure out what's wrong.

I've tried subsetting df[cols], taking it out of a list, etc.

```
data = {}
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x not in drops] # drops is list of unneeded columns

for uni in unique_sscs: # unique_sscs is a list of the values to use as the index
    for col in cols:
        data[uni] = [df[cols]]

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=unique_sscs, columns=cols)
```

Here's my result (they didn't paste, but all values show as NaN in Jupyter):

```
    lab_anl_method_name analysis_date   test_type   result_type_code    result_unit lab_name    sample_date work_order  sample_id
1904050740                                  
1904050820                                  
1904050825                                  
1904050830                                  
1904050840                                  
1904050845
```

Comment: You have to concat the values in `uni` and typecast it to a string. Then you can use it as a key in dict.

Comment: I don't understand. Why would I do that? uni values are already a string; I had to strip out some identifiers in the string for confidentiality reasons. Sorry if that was unclear.